# How to merge two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the first query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(otkupbody_mobile.bruto) AS bruto,
    SUM(otkupbody_mobile.neto) AS neto,
    SUM(otkupbody_mobile.muvla) AS muvla,
    COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
FROM otkupbody_mobile,
     otkupheader_mobile 
WHERE
(
    (otkupheader_mobile.unique_id=otkupbody_mobile.unique_id) 
)
```

This is the second:

```
SELECT
    SUM(otkupbody.bruto) AS bruto,
    SUM(otkupbody.neto) AS neto,
    SUM(otkupbody.muvla) AS muvla,
    COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
FROM otkupbody,
     otkupheader
WHERE
(
    (otkupheader.unique_id=otkupbody.unique_id) 
)
```

How can I make one query that will give me the results from both queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this if you want to merge *columns* together. The output would be **one** row with all the mentions columns:

```
Select  A.*
,   B.*
    From    (
    SELECT  SUM(otkupbody_mobile.bruto) AS bruto,
        SUM(otkupbody_mobile.neto) AS neto,
        SUM(otkupbody_mobile.muvla) AS muvla,
        COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
        FROM otkupbody_mobile,
        otkupheader_mobile 
        WHERE   otkupheader_mobile.unique_id=otkupbody_mobile.unique_id
    )   As  A
    ,   (
    SELECT  SUM(otkupbody.bruto) AS bruto,
        SUM(otkupbody.neto) AS neto,
        SUM(otkupbody.muvla) AS muvla,
        COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
        FROM otkupbody,
        otkupheader
        WHERE
        (
        (otkupheader.unique_id=otkupbody.unique_id) 
        )
    )   As  B
```

Or you could use a `UNION` clause between your queries if you want to merge rows.  For using `union` you should be careful that both results must have the same columns. The output would be **two** rows with columns of the **first** query. Like this:

```
    SELECT  SUM(otkupbody_mobile.bruto) AS bruto,
        SUM(otkupbody_mobile.neto) AS neto,
        SUM(otkupbody_mobile.muvla) AS muvla,
        COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
        FROM otkupbody_mobile,
        otkupheader_mobile 
        WHERE   otkupheader_mobile.unique_id=otkupbody_mobile.unique_id
UNION
    SELECT  SUM(otkupbody.bruto) AS bruto,
        SUM(otkupbody.neto) AS neto,
        SUM(otkupbody.muvla) AS muvla,
        COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
        FROM otkupbody,
        otkupheader
        WHERE
        (
        (otkupheader.unique_id=otkupbody.unique_id) 
        )
```

Comment: I'm really beginner in mySQL maybe it is stupid to ask but should I write A and B or should I write something else instead of A and B.

Comment: @user1702571 Dear friend, you should first be advised that the tags you were applied on the question was for SQL and not MySQL. Also about the A and B thing I should say that everything you put after "AS" in SQL or MySQL is called as alias (something like nickname). Purpose of declaring aliases is for preventing from using long names and making your code easy to write for referencing to objects. Hope it helps. I finally couldn't understand that whether it worked or not? You flagged the answer as correct, but you said it doesn't work. I didn't get your situation.

Comment: I thought it will have to work but Im doing something wrong. :)

Comment: @user1702571 Let me know about the details, maybe I could help you. ;) I'm waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT 
SUM(otkupbody_mobile.bruto) AS bruto,
SUM(otkupbody_mobile.neto) AS neto,
SUM(otkupbody_mobile.muvla) AS muvla,
COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
FROM otkupbody_mobile,
otkupheader_mobile 
WHERE
(
(otkupheader_mobile.unique_id=otkupbody_mobile.unique_id) 
)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
SUM(otkupbody.bruto) AS bruto,
SUM(otkupbody.neto) AS neto,
SUM(otkupbody.muvla) AS muvla,
COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
FROM otkupbody,
otkupheader
WHERE
(
(otkupheader.unique_id=otkupbody.unique_id) 
)
```

If you don't need duplicates, instead of `UNION ALL` use plain `UNION`

Comment: This is also OK but is there a way the results to be summarized in a single row becuse columns are the same in both tables. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then you should use the first solution what Mohammad Goudarzi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL. To summarize, use a SUM on the result. Like this:

```
select sum(bruto), sum(neto), sum(muvla), sum(broj_bali) from (
  SELECT 
  SUM(otkupbody_mobile.bruto) AS bruto,
  SUM(otkupbody_mobile.neto) AS neto,
  SUM(otkupbody_mobile.muvla) AS muvla,
  COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
  FROM otkupbody_mobile,
  otkupheader_mobile 
  WHERE
  (
  (otkupheader_mobile.unique_id=otkupbody_mobile.unique_id) 
  )
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  SUM(otkupbody.bruto) AS bruto,
  SUM(otkupbody.neto) AS neto,
  SUM(otkupbody.muvla) AS muvla,
  COUNT(*) AS broj_bali
  FROM otkupbody,
  otkupheader
  WHERE
  (
  (otkupheader.unique_id=otkupbody.unique_id) 
  )
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4d11/4)

Comment: Great this is ok but I kinda wanted the results to be summarized in a single row . Thanks a lot .

Comment: I have updated the query now to do exactly that. The SQL Fiddle example is also updated.